# SLComposeViewController doesn't handle tap on Cancel

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, sharing

I'm using SLComposeViewController to share data to Facebook. I need to know if user tap Post or Cancel button, but in block

```
SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler myBlock = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
            if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultDone) {
                NSLog(@"Done");  
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Cancelled");
            }

            [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
        };
```

I'm getting Done in both cases, after tapping Cancel and after tapping Post. Have anyone some ideas what is wrong?

**UPDATE**
This bug is being discussed [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/962985360399542/). Thanks to Amudi

Comment: I did exactly the same what you've done above and your code seems okay. Is there any chance that you are missing something in somewhere else ?

Comment: @miletliyusuf I don't think so

Comment: Are you testing this on a physical device with the Facebook app installed? If so, what version of the Facebook app do you have?

Comment: @MingLi version of Facebook app is 30.0

Comment: Hmm, it should work with 30, I think there was an issue with v29.

Comment: It's being discussed in [this bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/962985360399542/).